# Match integers at end of line

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a way to check if a certain line is of the following form:

```
[random text A-Za-z0-9 etc.] [integer] [integer]
```

So basically I want to check if the line ends with two integers and has some text before. I would also like to match those two integers and the random text part, since I need to process/store them separately.

I would prefer suggestions based on regular expressions.

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(.*)(\d)(\d)$
```

PHP code:

```
if (preg_match('/^(.*)(\d)(\d)$/', $str, $m)) {
    print_r($m);
}
```

Comment: It does not seem to work with this input string: ``Informatica 22 100``

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of anubhava I formed a regular expression that works:

```
'/^(.+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)$/'
```

Test:

```
test line: Informatica 22 100
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "Informatica 22 100"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Informatica"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "100"
}
```

Comment: it would be better if it is `^(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)$`